# Retrieve fillable fields in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.6

In laravel 5.4, I'm able to retrieve fillable fields by using `fillable` index of model instance.

```
$model = new AnyClass();
dd($model['fillable']);
```

The above code prints all fillable fields of `AnyClass`. But the same code prints `null` on laravel 5.6. I know I can retrieve fillable fields using `$model->getFillable()`. My question is what is the reason / why it is not working in laravel 5.6 but works in 5.4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at Laravel's source code you'll see the difference.

The Model class, which is extended by the application models, implements the `ArrayAccess` interface, which, among others, force the class to define the `offsetGet` method.

In Laravel 5.4 the `offsetGet` method looks like:

```
public function offsetGet($offset)
{
    return $this->$offset;
}
```

which means that if you call `$model['fillable']`, you actually call `$model->offsetGet('fillable')` which actually returns the `fillable` property of the class.

I couldn't find the Laravel 5.6 tag but I'm pretty sure it is the same code as Laravel 5.5.45. In this version the `offsetGet` method was changed to:

```
public function offsetGet($offset)
{
    return $this->getAttribute($offset);
}
```

which means that it actually returns the attribute if found or null otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

From the upgrade guide [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade#upgrade-5.5.0) I believe this is the answer to the question:

> **Model Methods & Attribute Names**
>
> To prevent accessing a model's private properties when using array access, it's no longer possible to have a model method with the same name as an attribute or property. Doing so will cause exceptions to be thrown when accessing the model's attributes via array access (`$user['name']`) or the `data_get` helper function.

Answer (score 3):

In **Laravel 7**, I'm doing this by calling the **getFillable** method on a new instance of my model. Like so:

```
$model = new MyModel();            
$fillable = $model->getFillable();
```

Comment: This also works in Laravel 8 with Php 8.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party but I don't like the concept of having to always instance a Model, specially if you're using [Eloquent serialization](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-serialization).

Let's say you wanted to build some filters, but wanted to whitelist the columns based on the model's fillable. You don't want to instance an entire model, so you can instead use reflection:

```
(new ReflectionClass(MyModel::class))->getDefaultProperties()['fillable']
```

[See it working over at 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/bEnRq) - Here I demonstrate why you potentially wouldn't want to instance this model due to having serialization and always eager loading.

Answer (score 0):

If want to check does Laravel `Eloquent Model` has a [fillable](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#mass-assignment) field/attribute from `$fillable` array you can check it in Model context:

```
<?php
use Models\MyModel;
$checkKeyFillable = 'title'; //for example
if ((new MyModel())->isFillable($checkKeyFillable)) {
    // fillable
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change the property in the class to `public $fillable = [` instead of `protected $fillable = [`